# How to access a string in a class stored in an array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a string (titleName) stored in a class (newNoteBook) stored in an array (myLibrary). I was trying to access it, but I only get a (null) printed in the log.

What am I doing wrong?

```
-(void) setupLibrary {

    NoteBook *newNoteBook = [[NoteBook alloc] init];

    newNoteBook.titleName = @"TEST";
    NSLog(@"titleName:%@", newNoteBook.titleName); // this prints TEST in the log
    [myLibrary addObject:newNoteBook];
    NSLog(@"titleName:%@", [[self.myLibrary objectAtIndex:0] titleName]); // this prints (null) in the log)
}
```

There is nothing fancy in my class... simply:

```
@interface NoteBook : NSObject {

NSString *titleName; }


@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *titleName;
@end

@implementation NoteBook
@synthesize titleName;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible reasons:

- `myLibrary` (the instance variable) is `nil`;
- `self.myLibrary` is `nil` or its backing instance variable isn’t `myLibrary`;
- `[self.myLibrary objectAtIndex:0]` is not the same object as `newNoteBook` because there was at least one other element in `self.myLibrary`.

---

**Edit:** you need to create a new mutable array and assign it to your property/instance variable `myLibrary`:

```
self.myLibrary = [NSMutableArray array];
```

or

```
myLibrary = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Where you should this depend on how your class is used. If an instance of your class should always have valid `myLibrary`, a good place to do that is in `-init`:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        myLibrary = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to lazily create `myLibrary` only when `-setupLibrary` is executed, create it in that method:

```
-(void) setupLibrary {
    self.myLibrary = [NSMutableArray array];

    NoteBook *newNoteBook = [[NoteBook alloc] init];
    …
}
```

Don’t forget to release it in your `-dealloc` method:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [myLibrary release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I achieve that myLibrary or self.myLibrary is not nil? All I have done so far with myLibrary is that I've declared it in my header as `NSMutableArray *myLibrary; @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myLibrary;` and implementation `@synthesize myLibrary;`. As for the third possible reason: this is the first object added to myLibrary, so I guess there can't be another one. Sorry if this is basic, but I don't get it. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Just solved it... it must be myLibrary = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; ... I should have known!

Comment: Thanks also about the clarification about the not needing to typecast... it looked way too complicated.

Comment: @never Great; I’ve edited my answer anyway. Don’t forget to release the array in your `-dealloc` method!

Comment: Thanks every so much! This really helped a lot. Slightly off-topic: Good luck with your travels and do let me know when you're down in Oxford.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
NSLog(@"titleName:%@", ((NoteBook *)[self.myLibrary objectAtIndex:0]).titleName);
```

Comment: There’s no need for the type cast since the return type of `-objectAtIndex:` is `id`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not type casting object from array -

```
NSLog(@"titleName:%@", [(NoteBook*)[self.myLibrary objectAtIndex:0] titleName]);
```

and you should alloc your array before adding object to it -

```
myLibrary = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: There’s no need for the type cast since the return type of `-objectAtIndex:` is `id`.

Comment: thanks, I didn't alloc myLibrary of course! Thanks for your help. As for the type casting, NSLog(@"titleName:%@", [[self.myLibrary objectAtIndex:0] titleName]); works fine and looks (in my beginner's eyes) a little bit less complicated than what you suggested?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSLog(@"titleName:%@", [self.myLibrary objectAtIndex:0].titleName);
```

Is correct as they said before you don't need to cast.